# Small Android Game

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android. I want to make a small game on android. Please suggest me which game should i make..? And also provide some detail about that game. Please help me...

Comment: I don't have 125 reputation to vote it down! :(

Comment: Sir. No. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making any "tapping game." e.g. something like tapping on the screen to kill bugs that appear on any random position.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could try making a snake like game but instead of hitting buttons or tapping the screen for movement you could use a turn of the phone for a change in direction.

2) You could make a multi-player pong game. I mean actual foot movement too. Depending on how much GPS polling you could do you could, in theory, create a pong game where two people had to physically move to stop the ball.

Comment: Sir may i get help in Game code..? so i can take help in coding of that simple game...

Comment: 2) gave me an amazing idea! See you in 1-2 months when I'm a millionaire, Nick Campbell! @Pushpendra - No, no one is going to give you game code unless you try yourself. Also, read the posting FAQ and guide.

Comment: @Klaus cool. I hope it works out for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can start developing arkanoid. See more details about that type of games here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkanoid